# Microsoft Graph group calendar list events not working

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

List events method for Group Calendar is not working.
I'm trying to retrieve all events from group calendar using following method:
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_events to no avail. 
I'm invoking it by

```
    GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/events
```

Results I'm receiving are

```
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the API not supporting this method at the moment?

Edit:
Group response:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
"id": "{id}",
"classification": null,
"createdDateTime": "2017-01-31T11:20:00Z",
"description": "1",
"displayName": "doctest",
"groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
],
"mail": "{email}",
"mailEnabled": true,
"mailNickname": "doctest",
"onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
"onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
"proxyAddresses": [
    "SMTP:{email}"
],
"renewedDateTime": "2017-01-31T11:20:00Z",
"securityEnabled": false,
"visibility": "Public"
}
```

Group that works (non sandbox tenant):

```
 {
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
"id": "{id}",
"classification": null,
"createdDateTime": "2016-12-13T16:47:53Z",
"description": "asd",
"displayName": "UploadTest",
"groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
],
"mail": "{email}",
"mailEnabled": true,
"mailNickname": "asd",
"onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
"onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
"onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
"proxyAddresses": [
    "SMTP:{email}"
],
"renewedDateTime": "2016-12-13T16:47:53Z",
"securityEnabled": false,
"visibility": "Public"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the formatted results of calling

`GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}`

Comment: That error response, ErrorItemNotFound, is not something I can repro.  I get a ErrorInvalidGroup error if I provide an unknown group id.

Comment: Please also validate the group is of type "Unified" only unified Groups (aka. Office 365 groups) have a calendar, files, notes and conversations

Comment: I think I've found out what the issue is. The tenant that I'm using for testing is a sandbox tenant (created in MS partner center). When tested on real tenant the API call is working. Is there some documentation available for which parts of the graph API are not available to the sandbox tenants?

Comment: There shouldn't be any differences. Could you post the JSON for the working group as well? Curious is there is a configuration difference.

Comment: I've posted the JSON for the working group as well.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT

Comment: Is anyone else still hitting this issue?